# python based amazon web scraper working fine on local machine but getting blocked after deployment

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, django-rest-framework

I have built an Amazon product price tracker and the code works perfectly fine on Django local server but after deploying it, it is getting blocked by amazon. what could be the cause and how can I solve it?

**utils.py**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from django.conf import settings
# Windows 10 with Google Chrome
user_agent_desktop = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '\
'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 '\
'Safari/537.36'

headers = { 'User-Agent': user_agent_desktop}
def getproduct(url):
    result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup)
    price = 0
    deal_price = 0
    title = soup.find('span',attrs={'id':'productTitle'}).text.strip()
    '''
    other scraping code
    '''
    return product
```

Comment: Its probably the fact that you are running on a known cloud host, likely even on AWS itself :D

Comment: I'm running it on Heroku.

Comment: @AkashSingh did you solve it?